# jquery datatable load limited data

Tags: jquery, datatables

This is giving some error and it loads the entire table data in one page itself. Any solutions? 
I have used ajax request to fetch the json data, it does everything correctly except lazy loading the data.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var table = $('#inbox').dataTable( {


            "processing": true,
            "deferRender":    true,     
            "ajax": {
                "url" : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Inbox_redirect/inbox",
                "type" : "GET",
                "dataSrc": "",
                "ContentType" : "json"

            },
            "columns" : [ 
                {"data" : "mailId"},
                {"data" : "mailSender"},
                {"data" : "mailSubject"},
                {"data" : "mailContent"},
                {"data" : "mailSendDate"} ],
            "serverSide": true,

        } );
    } );
    </script>
```

Comment: Is the return data from ajax correct or not? maybe try to print out the size of return data in ajax firstly.

Comment: there is a parameter called `draw` , please check [this](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side), it might help you.....

Comment: It is correctly returned from ajax call

Comment: @NikitaDhiman , try this one ,. [this](http://mbahcoding.com/tutorial/php/codeigniter/codeigniter-simple-server-side-datatable-example.html) is the best example i have ever seen . i have  implemented it my several website. its working like charm , same like your requirement. , let me know if you still need any help

Comment: can you see any error in the console?

Comment: @ArunKumaresh , she said she want to load some limited data,  she is not getting any error with that code..

Comment: code doesn't have any error

Comment: After my page is loaded and when I check in console for what data have been loaded in console->network->filename->preview I see all my json data have been loaded. Now I want that only the data which is presently shown to the user (like 10 of 100) should be fetched instead of whole 100 json objects

Comment: @Punit....when I tried your example it doesn't give me any data in my table toh it has been fetching all the data again

Answer (score 0):

You have server-side processing mode enabled with `serverSide: true`, which **will** load one page data only. You need to use [ssp.class.php](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php) from DataTables distribution to perform server-side processing on the server as well.

See [this example](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html) for code and demonstration.